# JavaFX set Button text via CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx, skinning

I googled for this, but couldn't find anything. I know that I can style a Buttons text, background colour etc, but I would like to change the text itself.

This is what I've tried (of course the actual end result is more complex, but this will do):

```
Button#playButton {
    -fx-background-color: #ddd;
    -fx-text: "Play";
}
```

the background colour is correctly applied, but the text does not change.

**Edit:** The way to go seems to be a custom property, if someone has knowledge within that field I would love a concise explanation and implementation, that could save me hours of trial and error with the few sources I found!

Comment: Not possible, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#button

Comment: Maybe some way to replace the text set in the code by an icon? that would suffice, although I do not see much hope :c

Comment: Why do you want to set the text in CSS? It is not really part of the "style" of he button.

Comment: I want to be able to either show text or an icon on a button, depending on the css, to make skinning possible

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot set the text of your button using css. But hey! In the other hand, you can still display an icon in your button using css!

You only need to add this to your css :

```
-fx-graphic : url("relative path to your icon");
```

In case your icon is repeated in the button, then add this as well :

```
-fx-background-repeat : no-repeat;
```

Comment: Setting the icon is trivial, but what if the icon should replace the text? Tho it seems to me that it is possible with a custom property... I'll have to do some more research

Comment: can you explain me this further? Do you have a text by desfault, and then at some event (say MouseClicked event) you need to replace the text with an icon?

Comment: If it is the case then it can also be achieved using css as: Button#playButton:pressed{-fx-graphic:url(); } ... and to remove and existing text, on the button just use, btnName.setText(""); in an action event and it will work along with css and will do your job ^^

Comment: No, a skin (as css) should be able to either define a text or an icon

Comment: As I've mentioned earlier, the icon can be showed using only css and no extra coding. You can set the button to only have an icon(graphic) without text in it with Scene Builder. After selecting the button, on the right side(properties) there's an option called "Content Display" in that Combo-box of choices, choose "Graphic only" so it will not show any text, then to show the icon, use css as I've mentioned in the answer, and if it needs to be changed during multiple events like, "hover", "click" you can still define them within your css with pseudo classes like "#id:hover","#id:pressed"